# Object Disposed exception when scrolling datagrid view left to right

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, datagridview, windows

I am using Linq to SQL classes for managing data and using the following code to bind data to dataGridview in Windows Forms. exception is thrown when i am trying to scroll the datagrdview from left to right.

The two tables involved here are  :

**billing_UserRole**

RoleId PK

RoleName

CreatedTS

UpdatedTS

**billing_User**

UserId PK //This is referenced in some other tables as well.

RoleId FK

Username

Password

FirstName

LastName

CreatedTS

UpdatedTS

**The create tables queries are following**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[billing_UserRole](
bk_UserRoleId BIGINT IDENTITY(100,1) NOT NULL,
bk_UserRoleName NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
bk_CreatedTS DATETIME NULL,
bk_UpdatedTS DATETIME NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_billingUserRole] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [bk_UserRoleId] ASC 
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


/* TABLE NAME : billing_User */
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[billing_User](
    bk_UserId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    bk_Username NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    bk_Password NVARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL DEFAULT('none'),
    bk_FirstName NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    bk_LastName NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    bk_MobileNo NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    bk_Address NVARCHAR(2048) NULL DEFAULT('none'),
    bk_Remarks NVARCHAR(2048) NULL DEFAULT('none'),
    bk_UserRoleId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    bk_CreatedTS DATETIME NULL,
    bk_UpdatedTS DATETIME NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_billingUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [bk_UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
CONSTRAINT [FK_billingUser_billingUserRole] FOREIGN KEY(bk_UserRoleId) REFERENCES [dbo].[billing_UserRole](bk_UserRoleId)
)
```

Code in form to bind datagridview on form_load

```
 private void UserManagementForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (BillingKioskDataLayerDataContext dc = new BillingKioskDataLayerDataContext())
                {

                    Table<billing_User> UserTable = dc.GetTable<billing_User>();
                    var UserList = UserTable.Select(o=>o).ToList();
                    billing_UserBindingSource.DataSource = UserList;
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = billing_UserBindingSource;


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);   
            }

        }
```

Here's the code where the exception is thrown. It's an auto generated code.  Why does it happen so ? **I only get this exception when i scroll the DataGridView Left to right to view the remaining fields.**

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="billing_UserRole_billing_User", Storage="_billing_UserRole", ThisKey="bk_UserRoleId", OtherKey="bk_UserRoleId", IsForeignKey=true)]
            public billing_UserRole billing_UserRole
            {
                get
                {
                    return this._billing_UserRole.Entity; **// I get DisposedObjectException :Cannot access a disposed object here**
                }
                set
                {
                    billing_UserRole previousValue = this._billing_UserRole.Entity;
                    if (((previousValue != value) 
                                || (this._billing_UserRole.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
                    {
                        this.SendPropertyChanging();
                        if ((previousValue != null))
                        {
                            this._billing_UserRole.Entity = null;
                            previousValue.billing_Users.Remove(this);
                        }
                        this._billing_UserRole.Entity = value;
                        if ((value != null))
                        {
                            value.billing_Users.Add(this);
                            this._bk_UserRoleId = value.bk_UserRoleId;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this._bk_UserRoleId = default(long);
                        }
                        this.SendPropertyChanged("billing_UserRole");
                    }
                }
            }
```

stack trace :

```
 at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.GetTable(Type type)
   at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetDataMemberQuery(MetaDataMember member, Expression[] keyValues)
   at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.DeferredSourceFactory`1.ExecuteKeyQuery(Object[] keyValues)
   at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.DeferredSourceFactory`1.Execute(Object instance)
   at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.DeferredSourceFactory`1.DeferredSource.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Linq.EntityRef`1.get_Entity()
   at BillingKiosk.billing_User.get_billing_UserRole() in e:\XGHProjects\BillingKiosk\BillingKiosk\BillingKioskDataLayer.designer.cs:line 663
```

Comment: Nope @GrantWinney No Inner Exception. But this is what i see in the exception window {"Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'."}

Comment: added the stack trace above

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are experiencing Lazy or Deferred Loading of columns in a related entity.
You can use DataLoadOptions.LoadWith Method to include the related columns.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

By the way: very easy to establish if this is realy the case: remove the Using() on your datacontext. [Only for diagnostics...]. If it works well, Lazy loading...